# There is a black bottom space below the camera

Tags: ios, swift, camera, uitabbarcontroller, uiimagepickercontroller

I am presenting an `UIImagePickerController` from a `UITabBarController`.

```
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = .Camera
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
        imagePicker.showsCameraControls = false

        presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I have explicitly set `showsCameraControls` to false to put my custom overlay view on top of camera.But why there is a black space on the bottom?any helps?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The camera aspect ratio is 4:3,you have to apply a transform scale so that you can get full screen

Swift

```
let screenSize = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size
let aspectRatio:CGFloat = 4.0/3.0
let scale = screenSize.height/screenSize.width * aspectRatio
self.imagePikerViewController.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scale, scale);
```

Screen shot

[image]

Objective C

```
CGSize screenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
float aspectRatio = 4.0/3.0;
float scale = screenSize.height/screenSize.width * aspectRatio;
self.imagePikerViewController.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scale, scale);
```

Comment: a hidden gem of stackoverflow. This helped immensely. Thank you!

Comment: Does this still work with iOS 10? I tried this code and it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Not working for iOS 10. any other solution for this?

Comment: @Leo This works to remove the bottom black bar but it makes the camera zoomed in. The actual image captured in different (very zoomed out) from what is looked like while capturing the image.