# UIImagePickerController: correct way to show a full screen camera?

Tags: ios, swift, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

I've seen that by default, when displaying a `UIImagePickerController` with type camera, a black bar at the bottom of screen appears at the bottom.

I want the camera view to be full screen. I've read several posts related to this topic like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31152040/there-is-a-black-bottom-space-below-the-camera) or [this other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674375/uiimagepickercontroller-doesnt-fill-screen/15803947) that calculate a `cameraViewTransform`. I tried and this solution looks like a bit complicated and it looks like the camera is "zoomed in".

I also tried to show the image picker setting `modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen`, but I see no difference, the black bottom bar still appears.

Is there any more appropriate way to solve this?

Comment: This is well discussed in the answers you pointed to (and others). Your repetition of the question adds nothing to the mix; there is no point asking again just because you don't like the existing answers. If you don't want to do what others have advised in the past, then just don't use the image picker controller; use AVFoundation to create your own camera interface instead.

Comment: @matt That answer is a bit old (2010), maybe a different solution could be possible currently